# How to center align text vertically from icon height center

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Am trying to make the text start from the center of the icon vertically, where am not able to make it using margin, any pointers.
 below is my code snippet that am using.
[image]

```css
.topcontainer{
 text-align: left;
 }
 .secondtopcontainer{
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 55px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: inline;
 }
 
 .icon-color{
 color: green;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topcontainer">
   <i class="far fa-minus-circle fa-3x icon-color" style="float: left;"></i>
   <div class="secondtopcontainer" style="margin-top: 43px;">
   <span class="icon-color">This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.</span>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: drop the "display: inline;" bit

Comment: What about the second text line? Shall it display under the icon?

Comment: Next line also should start from same as first line vertically and horizontally, like icon is separated from text.

Comment: Did you give `vertical-align: middle;` a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `float` the icon. Also try to avoid inline styles and pay attention to proper indentation.

You can achieve the *side-by-side* effect with [`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on the `.topcontainer` and the top offset with a [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) on the `.secondtopcontainer`, that is half of the line height:

[image]

```css
.topcontainer {
  display: flex;
}

.secondtopcontainer {
  padding: .75em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.icon-color {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="topcontainer">
  <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-3x icon-color"></i>
  <div class="secondtopcontainer">
    <span class="icon-color">This Text should start from center of the Icon height. This Text should start from center of the Icon height. This Text should start from center of the Icon height. This Text should start from center of the Icon height. This Text should start from center of the Icon height.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the container, you can use the `height` +`line-height` combo

```css
.topcontainer{
 text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .secondtopcontainer{

 }
 
 .icon-color{
 color: green;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topcontainer">
   <i class="far fa-minus-circle fa-3x icon-color" style="float: left;"></i>
   <div class="secondtopcontainer" style="margin-top: 43px;">
   <span class="icon-color">This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.</span>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb8nz.png)

I'm not a professional in html but this might be the solution to your problem.
Just make the topcontainer, second container and the i element that contains the image float:left; and add a top margin to the i element that contains the img.

```css
 .topcontainer {
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
 }
 .secondtopcontainer {
  float:left;
  color:black;
 }
 i.icon {
 float:left;
 margin-top:7px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topcontainer">
   <i class="icon"> <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/blackvariant/button-ui-system-apps/1024/Terminal-icon.png" height="32" width="32""> </i>
   <div class="secondtopcontainer">
   <p class="icon">This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.This TExt should start from center of the Icon height.</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry in advance if I misunderstood your question. 
Scriptkiddie27